# Does this Swift code create a reference cycle between ParentClass and ChildClass?

Tags: swift

In an interview, I was presented with the following Swift code that includes two classes, `ParentClass` and `ChildClass`. I'm uncertain about whether this code results in a reference cycle between these classes. Could someone kindly provide clarification?

In my assessment, it appears that a reference cycle exists because both classes reference each other.

```
 class ParentClass {
    lazy var child: ChildClass = {
        return ChildClass()
    }()
    
    func showChildClassName() {
        child.showParentClassName()
    }
}

class ChildClass {
    var parentClass: ParentClass = {
        return ParentClass()
    }()
    
    func showParentClassName() {
        print("Parent class name")
    }
}
```

Comment: In this example, it's not. You just defined two classes that have a store property for each other. Retain cycle will occur when you declare a class that holds a strong reference to another. E.g `var parentClass = ParentClass(); var childClass = ChildClass(); parentClass.child = childClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example does not create a retain cycle, but it is also misleading and probably not useful.

As @son says in their comment, a ParentClass object creates an instance of ChildClass and holds a strong reference to it.

Similarly, a ChildClass object creates an instance of ParentClass and holds a strong reference to it. However, they don't point to each other.

Unless you manually cause a "matched set" where they each point to each other, you're not going to have a circular ring of strong references.

If you used code like the below, it **would** cause a retain cycle:

```
 class ParentClass {
    lazy var child: ChildClass = {
        return ChildClass()
    }()
 }

class ChildClass {
    var parentClass: ParentClass = {
        return ParentClass()
    }()
}

let aParent = ParentClass()
let aChild = ChildClass()

aChild.parentClass = aChild // This line causes a retain cycle.
```

The last line of that code causes the parent to point to the child and the child to point to the parent. Since they each point to each other with strong references, it causes a retain cycle.

Typically you'd create a child object that takes a parent as a parameter, and saves it in a weak variable. (The general rule is that parent->child relationships should be strong, but child->parent references should be weak. The parent is responsible for the child, and not visa-versa.) If you do that then you can have parent/child pairs that point to each other but you avoid a retain cycle.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not cause a retain cycle.

You can prove it by running the code below. It creates an instance of `ParentClass` and retrieves the `parentClass` reference of its `child`.

`ObjectIdentifier` in the `print` lines shows the memory address of the instance and you will see that the addresses of `parent` and `childsParent` are different

```
let parent = ParentClass()
let child = parent.child
let childsParent = child.parentClass

print(ObjectIdentifier(parent))
print(ObjectIdentifier(childsParent))
```

Comment: You can use `print(ObjectIdentifier(parent))` instead, which doesn't require unsafe memory management.